# Print a string till a particular character comes

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, char

I want the string to be printed till character ('e') comes.
Code which I tried:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
    int a,i,x;
    char b[10];
    char ch;
    //enter input string
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      scanf("%c",&b[i]);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       if(b[i]!='e')
           printf("%c",b[i]); 

    return 0;
    }
```

`Input:abcdefghij` 
`Actual output:abcdfghij` 
`Desired output:abcd` 
`Question :` Where am I wrong ?  Will putting a `break` inside `if block` work here?

Comment: To me your input and output are exactly the same, so I'm not sure why you need a program at all. And the "limit" thing is a bit unclear.

Comment: To start with, `for(i=0;i<=100;i++)` will not only exceed the array bounds, but leave no room to put mandatory string terminator `'\0'` after the characters that is expected of what you call a "string".

Comment: Why the loops?  Call scanf with %s. Not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", b)` would scan elements till newline character is entered and `printf("%s", b)` would print the string.

Comment: @sidyll, This code part of my another code, in this I wants to print string till only I enter.For ex.  input- qwert, then output should be-qwert, means I will have to store value 4(beacuse here length is 4) in some var. in first for loop and then I will run second for loop 4 time, so my question is how to store that 4 in first loop?

Comment: @Cherubim `scanf` with %s is unsafe; you might end up overflowing the stack (in this example). You can limit the number of read characters like this: `scanf ("%99s", b);`, but it's best to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

    int a,i,x;
    char b[10];
    char ch; 

    //enter input string
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&b[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(b[i]=='e')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

re

Answer (score 3):

This is much cleaner if you want to use scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char b[101];

   scanf("%100s", b);

   printf("%s\n", b);

   return(0);
}
```

Or even better.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int main()
{
   char b[MAX_LENGTH+1]; // add 1 for the terminating zero

   scanf("%100s", b);

   printf("%s\n", b);

   return(0);
}
```

This one uses fgets to read the entire line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 100

int main()
{
   char b[MAX_LENGTH];

   fgets(b, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);

   printf("%s", b);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Where is space for the terminator?

Comment: Is is unfortunate that you cannot use `MAX_LENGTH` in `scanf`. (If you used `fgets` then you could pass `sizeof b`.) But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3313798/4142924) shows how to limit the input length of `scanf` programmatically.

Comment: With OP's code, or nearly so, user could enter "Mike Collins" and print out "MikeCollins".  With this code, all it prints is "Mike\n".

Comment: @WeatherVane Of use [Stringification of a macro value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653214/stringification-of-a-macro-value) - at compile time.

Comment: @WeatherVane To use `MAX_LENGTH` in `scanf()`, stringification example: `#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(a) #a` `#define STRINGIFY(a) STRINGIFY_HELPER(a)` `scanf("%" STRINGIFY(MAX_LENGTH) "s", b);`

Comment: A better approach might be to use getchar or getc inside the loop if you don't want to stop on whitespace. Using scanf seems to be overkill if we're only reading one character at a time. Even better, just use fgets() to read the entire line and then parse as necessary.

Comment: @Mike Collins, If I want stop printing after a particular character then what check should I place?

Comment: You would need to check each line after is is read in. The disadvantage is that it would read the entire line before checking. However, it MIGHT still be faster than reading one character at a time.In any case I don't think the performance would be significant.

Answer (score 2):

> How to print a string till limit?

What code *should* do is use `fgets()`.

Avoid using `scanf()`.  Is is too easy to use wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char b[100];
  if (fgets(b, sizeof b, stdin)) {

    // If code needs to lop off the potential \n at the end
    b[strcspn(b, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", b);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Advanced issues include how to handle excessively long input lines and error handling - not shown here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes!

1. If you are initializing your loops from 0 then you need to set the condition till `i<100`.
2. Change your format specifiers to `%s`.
3. Change your IF statement to `if(b[i]!='\0')`.

Comment: ok agreed for i<100. Here b[i]=='\0' will be at i=100 but I need to print the string only till I enter and not till 100

Comment: Why change to `%s`?

Comment: %s denotes a string formally. A String is a contiguous sequence of characters. @Weather Vane

Comment: but I am dealing here with character, so I am using %c

Comment: I get it, you are dealing with the character but because of %c you won't be able to enter a string or print a string. @priya

Comment: Alright, my bad! I thought the question was of reversing a string. Anyways, edited! @Weather Vane

Comment: @Ashi, here I am entering in for loop so using %c

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i;
    char b[10];

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&b[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(b[i]=='e')
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%c",b[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```